# What are the common tennis terms in Japanese?

Tags: english-to-japanese, sports

Particularly for

- [advantage set / tiebreaker set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_scoring_system#Scoring_a_tiebreak_game)
- game
- set
- match
- love (the term used for 0 or a no score situation)
- 15/30/40
- deuce
- advantage in / advantage out

Comment: The Wikipedia page lists all of the terms for you: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%86%E3%83%8B%E3%82%B9#.E3.83.86.E3.83.8B.E3.82.B9.E7.94.A8.E8.AA.9E

Comment: Thanks @Kurausukun. I assumed it would mirror the outline of the English Wikipedia article (which doesn't have a section for terms) but I should've checked anyway.

It covers most terms except for the first and last bullet points. For the last bullet, equivalents of "advantage in" and "advantage out" would be ideal, but just the word for advantage would be useful to me too.

Comment: I don't claim to be an expert about this, but some quick searching gave me the terms アドバンテージサーバー and アドバンテージレシーバー.

Comment: In sports, the Japanese seems to like to use English (or other official languages) directly. And a few site: http://www.thetennisdaily.jp/know_tennisgame.asp  http://www.wowow.co.jp/sports/tennis/guide_words.html

Answer (score 5):

advantage set / tiebreaker set

アドバンテージセット/タイブレークセット

game

ゲーム

set

セット

match

マッチ

love (the term used for 0 or a no score situation)

ラブ

15/30/40

フィフティーン/サーティー/フォーティー

deuce

デュース

advantage in / advantage out

アドバンテージ 太郎(player name) / 二郎(player name)

As for advantage in/out, they used to call the players' name who took the point following with 'advantage' but nowadays they prefer to call advantage in/out just as westerners do.

In Japan, tennis players tend to be classy people since the Japanese began to play tennis, so I think most tennis terms were imported in their original forms because tennis was spread among the intellectual class where no translation needed, as opposed to baseball which has many Japanese-English terms!

The tennis terms that don't make sense in Japanese that I know are shank, overhead and bagel in Japanese respectively フレームに当たる？(I'm not sure) , スマッシュ, and 6-0.

Comment: This is great! One more question: how do you say "all" like in "fifteen all"?